# ERROR 1064 (42000) : You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm running the following SQL:

```
create table group(groupID varchar(15) primary key,
group_name varchar(30),
name_of_member varchar(100),
studentID varchar(15),
foreign key(studentID) references student(studentID))engine=innodb;
```

But it's not working.  I'm getting the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) : You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax.... near
>   group(groupID varchar(15) primary key,
>   group_name varchar(30),name_of_member
>   va' at line 1

PLEASE HELP ME... :(

Comment: As @Nathan said in his answer, don't use reserved words as table or column names unless you want lots of annoyances. Study the list of MySQL reserved words and then re-name your tables/columns to avoid naming things GROUP, SELECT, DELETE, and so forth. And *please* format the code in your questions in the future - highlight the code and press Ctrl+K, or click the button with the `{}` image, or indent each line of code by 4 spaces. It makes it much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @KenWhite  I was getting the same error but solved it by referring to the given answer. Is "order" a keyword in MySql because when i changed table name from order to orders then the query executed without any error. As per my knowledge "order by" is a keyword

Comment: @ShantanuNandan: ORDER is a keyword because it's part of ORDER BY; it's enough to confuse the parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group` is a keyword [think `select sum(column) from sometable group by name`]. You'll need to name your table something different.

Some DBMSes will let you use keywords as table/column names, but they need to be escaped. i.e. in MSSQL, you'd use `create table [group](...)`.

Comment: The escape character for mysql is the back tick: `

Comment: thnk you.. i just change it from group to PARTY... it's working.. thx :)